# Getting database info and sending it as XML file in django

Tags: sql-server, django, xml

I'm working on a django webservice which needs to handle database information from a SQL-server database. My database structure looks like this:

[image: database diagram taken from SQL-Server's managment studio software.]

As you can see I've got a table which holds orders `Data_Orders` which is refrenced by the `Data_Models` tablewhich stores the relation between each order and the corresponding models. This table also refrences `Data_ModelColors` where an ID is stored used to determine the name of the color in the `Data_Color` table. last, there is a `Data_ModelSizes` table which holds the information i'm most intrested in, the ammount. Whith this setup I am able to specify the amount of models to add to the orders for each color and size.

Now I have to convert information from this database to XML files to send in a `HttpResponse` in django. As you can see each order also specifies a company to send it to(bottom left of the diagram). I need to generate XML files with orders for each company whenever I get a request from said company. I've created a function that is able to send an XML file in a `HttpResponse` like this:

```
def index(request):
    template = loader.get_template('orders/testTemplate.xml')
    tpcontext = {'orderinfo': 'testordername'}
    return HttpResponse(template.render(tpcontext, request))
```

I'm currently using a test template just to see if it's working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test1>
    <testing testid="test">
        <test attribute1 = "1">This is a test example to see if django likes XML: {{ orderinfo }}</test>
    </testing>
</test1>
```

and I've confirmed this setup works for this template. However I don't know how I would extend this to the functionallity I've described. I've created a template for the XML file i want to make:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<orders>
    {% for order in orderList %}
    <order id="{{ order.id }}">
        <models>
        {% for model in order.models %}
        <model id="{{ model.id }}">
            <name>{{model.name}}</name>
            {% for color in model.colors %}
            <color name="'{{color.name}}'">
                {% for size in color.sizes %}
                <sizeAmount name="'{{size.name}}'">{{size.amount}}</sizeAmount>
                {% endfor%}
            </color>
            {% endfor%}
        </model>
        {% endfor %}
        </models>
    </order>
    {% endfor %}
</orders>
```

Here I assumed I can just pass an `orderList` object as the context which contains a list of orders. each order then should contain a list of models, which in term holds the colors. for each color I store all of the sizes which then holds the amount for each size.

Here is a manually made preview of what I would like the output to look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<orders>
    <order id="13">
        <models>
            <model id="12">
                <name>pants</name>
                <color name="blue">
                    <sizeAmount name="L" >0</sizeAmount>
                    <sizeAmount name="XL" >3</sizeAmount>
                    <sizeAmount name="XXL" >11</sizeAmount>
                </color>
                <color name="red">
                    <sizeAmount name="L" >2</sizeAmount>
                    <sizeAmount name="XL" >6</sizeAmount>
                    <sizeAmount name="XXL" >0</sizeAmount>
                </color>
            </model>
            <model id="13">
                <name>jacket</name>
                <color name="green">
                    <sizeAmount name="S" >9</sizeAmount>
                    <sizeAmount name="L" >11</sizeAmount>
                    <sizeAmount name="XL" >32</sizeAmount>
                    <sizeAmount name="XXL" >0</sizeAmount>
                </color>
            </model>
        </models>
    </order>
    <order id="14">
        <models>
            <model id="15">
                <name>jacket</name>
                <color name="green">
                    <sizeAmount name="S" >0</sizeAmount>
                    <sizeAmount name="L" >0</sizeAmount>
                    <sizeAmount name="XL" >0</sizeAmount>
                    <sizeAmount name="XXL" >5</sizeAmount>
                </color>
            </model>
        </models>
    </order>
</orders>
```

Now my question is: How would I provide the context for this template? I know you can pass context like this: `tpcontext = {'orderinfo': 'testordername'}` and it will show up in the template but I don't know how to apply this to the database structure I have described above.

Also here are the models for the database:

```
class DataColors(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    name = models.CharField(db_column='Name', unique=True, max_length=255)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Data_Colors'


class DataCompanies(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    name = models.CharField(db_column='Name', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Data_Companies'


class DataModelcolors(models.Model):
    colorid = models.ForeignKey(DataColors, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='ColorID')  # Field name made lowercase.
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Data_ModelColors'


class DataModeldata(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    name = models.CharField(db_column='Name', max_length=255)  # Field name made lowercase.
    descript = models.CharField(db_column='Descript', max_length=2047, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Data_ModelData'


class DataModeldatacolors(models.Model):
    modeldataid = models.ForeignKey(DataModeldata, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='ModelDataID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    colorid = models.ForeignKey(DataColors, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='ColorID')  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Data_ModelDataColors'
        unique_together = (('modeldataid', 'colorid'),)


class DataModeldatasizes(models.Model):
    modeldataid = models.ForeignKey(DataModeldata, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='ModelDataID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    sizeid = models.ForeignKey('DataSizes', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='SizeID')  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Data_ModelDataSizes'
        unique_together = (('modeldataid', 'sizeid'),)


class DataModelsizes(models.Model):
    colorid = models.ForeignKey(DataModelcolors, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='ColorID')  # Field name made lowercase.
    sizeid = models.ForeignKey('DataSizes', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='SizeID')  # Field name made lowercase.
    amount = models.IntegerField(db_column='Amount')  # Field name made lowercase.
    amountfinished = models.IntegerField(db_column='AmountFinished')  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Data_ModelSizes'


class DataModels(models.Model):
    modelcolorid = models.ForeignKey(DataModelcolors, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='ModelColorID')  # Field name made lowercase.
    orderid = models.ForeignKey('DataOrders', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='OrderID')  # Field name made lowercase.
    modeldataid = models.ForeignKey(DataModeldata, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='ModelDataID')  # Field name made lowercase.
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Data_Models'


class DataOrdercompanies(models.Model):
    orderid = models.ForeignKey('DataOrders', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='OrderID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    companyid = models.ForeignKey(DataCompanies, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='CompanyID')  # Field name made lowercase.
    stagenumber = models.IntegerField(db_column='StageNumber')  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Data_OrderCompanies'
        unique_together = (('orderid', 'companyid'),)


class DataOrders(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    ordertimestamp = models.DateTimeField(db_column='OrderTimeStamp', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    finishtimestamp = models.DateTimeField(db_column='FinishTimeStamp', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    name = models.CharField(db_column='Name', max_length=255)  # Field name made lowercase.
    confirmed = models.IntegerField(db_column='Confirmed')  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Data_Orders'


class DataSizes(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    name = models.CharField(db_column='Name', unique=True, max_length=255)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Data_Sizes'
```

**EDIT:**

I'm trying to get this to work however it's not easy. I've tried doing this:

```
template = loader.get_template('orders/responseTemplate.xml')
ids = DataOrdercompanies.objects.filter(companyid=10).values('orderid')

tpcontext = {'orderList': DataOrders.objects.filter(id__in=ids)}
return HttpResponse(template.render(tpcontext, request))
```

curently the response XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<orders>

    <order id="16">
        <models>

        </models>
    </order>

</orders>
```

As suggested I also changed the template to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<orders>
    {% for order in orderList %}
    <order id="{{ order.id }}">
        <models>
        {% for model in order.models.all %}
        <model id="{{ model.id }}">
            <name>{{model.name}}</name>
            {% for color in model.colors.all %}
            <color name="'{{color.name}}'">
                {% for size in color.sizes.all %}
                <sizeAmount name="'{{size.name}}'">{{size.amount}}</sizeAmount>
                {% endfor%}
            </color>
            {% endfor%}
        </model>
        {% endfor %}
        </models>
    </order>
    {% endfor %}
</orders>
```

which seems to give me an empty orderList in the context. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: post your view code too, and what is the problem? have you executed it? to check if its working or not

Comment: I've posted the code for the view but only for running the test template and not the one below it because i don't know how I should obtain and manage all of the context I need to provide it.

Comment: The only context you would need for that template is `orderList`, which you're already passing, so I don't know what your question is.

Comment: Although note you probably mean `{% for model in order.models.all %}` etc. (Note, this would be easier if you had posted your models rather than a picture of some tables.)

Comment: @DanielRoseman I've added the models too. What i mean is that i don't know how to provide for the values for `orderList`. How do I get the info from the database inside the `orderList` parameter in such a way it will be usable by the template?

Comment: What? What don't you understand? Do you not know how to query objects from the database? Then you should go and do the tutorial, where that is well explained. (Also, don't call your foreignkey fields names ending in `id`.)

Comment: @DanielRoseman I've been trying. Could you take a look at my edit?

Answer (score 1):

Your models are hard to read and use; I realise that they probably started off autogenerated from an existing db schema, but you need to tidy them up more before they are usable.

The most important thing from your point of view is to recognise when you have many-to-many relationships, such as in Ordercompanies, and make those explicit. But you also need to do some renaming to follow Django conventions: start by dropping the `Data` prefix from all the model names, use proper InitialCaps format, and make them singular. Next drop the `id` suffix from the foreign keys, and give all the fields lower_case_with_underscore format names. So:

```
class Color(models.Model):
    ...

class Company(models.Model):
    orders = models.ManyToManyField('Order', through='OrderCompany')
    ...


# what's the point of this table?
class ModelColor(models.Model):
    color = models.ForeignKey(Color, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='ColorID')
    ...

class ModelData(models.Model):
    colors = models.ManyToManyField('Color', through='ModelDataColor')
    sizes = models.ManyToManyField('Size', through='ModelDataSize')
    ...

class ModelDataColor(models.Model):
    model_data = models.ForeignKey(ModelData, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='ModelDataID', primary_key=True)
    color = models.ForeignKey(Color, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='ColorID') 
    ...

class ModelDataSize(models.Model):
    model_data = models.ForeignKey(ModelData, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='ModelDataID', primary_key=True)
    size = models.ForeignKey('Size', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='SizeID')
    ...


class ModelSize(models.Model):
    color = models.ForeignKey(ModelColor, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='ColorID')
    size = models.ForeignKey('DataSize', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='SizeID')
    ...

class Model(models.Model):
    model_color = models.ForeignKey(ModelColor, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='ModelColorID')
    order = models.ForeignKey('Order', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='OrderID')
    model_data = models.ForeignKey(ModelData, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='ModelDataID')
    ...

class OrderCompany(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey('Order', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='OrderID', primary_key=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='CompanyID')
    stage_number = models.IntegerField(db_column='StageNumber')

    ...

class Order(models.Model):
    ...

class Size(models.Model):
    ...
```

(I haven't understood all your relations, so I may not have got all those right.)

So now you have a proper relation between Order and Company, you can query that directly:

```
company = Company.objects.get(id=10) # remember to use `get` for a single item
order_list = company.orders.all()
```

and pass that to the template.

Note you still aren't using the actual names of the relations or reverse relations in your template. Since the relationship between model and order does not define an explicit related_name, the default one is `model_set`; or, if you stuck with your original names, `datamodels_set`. You need to use that when you follow the relation:

```
{% for model in order.model_set.all %}
```

Similarly, the ForeignKey from Model to Color is called `model_color` in my version, or `modelcolorid` in yours; again, that's the name you need to use:

{% for color in model.model_color.all %}

I would say that this is a very complex set of models - and a complex task overall - for someone who is new to Django. You should probably start smaller, with just a couple of models, and experiment with the API until you understand it. It is actually easy to use, but you've made it hard by trying to learn too much at once.

Comment: Yes the models are autogenerated and, as of now, they are setup in a way that django can read the actual database. If I change the names of the models will django still be able to read these tables that allready excist? And if so will django not modify anyting to the point where other applications interacting with the database will no longer work?

Comment: Yes Django will use the table names as defined by the `db_table` Meta settings, and the fields as defined by their `db_column` attributes. And no, again you've set `managed=False` so Django won't modify anything about the db structure.

Comment: OK thank you! I'll try to implement it and see how it goes!

Comment: I'm now in the process of updating the template but some of the fields are empty, I'm trying to print out order_list to see the information in the list but it's just giving me: <QuerySet [<Order: Order object (16)>]>. Is there a better way to see what's inside this QuerySet in order to debug it?

Comment: You should define `__str__` methods for your models that return useful information.

Comment: I made __str__() methods for all of my models like for example this one: `return "Order:[" + self.id.__str__() + ", " + self.ordertimestamp + ", " + self.finishtimestamp + ", " + self.name + ", " + self.confirmed.__str__() + "] "` and the output of printing order_list now looks like this: `print(order_list)`. However I'm still getting some info from other models. Here(https://pastebin.com/24UWEWK4) is a new version of the template I'm using, would you mind taking a look? I'm able to see the `id` attributes for orders and models in the XML file and nothing else.